# Preserving order of YAML maps using Go

Tags: go, yaml

I'm trying to figure out how to read a YAML file in Go, while preserving the order of keys as ordered in the YAML doc. Most of the examples I've seen involve sorting the keys, but that won't work in my case. In addition, the YAML is arbitrarily structured (keys are user-defined, and values are a mix of string and string lists, also user-defined), which complicates matters.

go-yaml.v2 seems to do what I want (http://blog.labix.org/2014/09/22/announcing-yaml-v2-for-go), but I can't find any examples on how to use the ordering functionality. That, along with being completely new to Go, is leaving me pretty stumped.

I'd be happy to provide examples of the YAML I'm trying to parse, if needed.

Comment: Just use the `MapSlice` type from that package instead of a `map` in the data structure that you deserialize to.

Comment: The problem seems impossible to solve when attempting this at a deeper level of the yaml tree. A show stopper?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var data = `
  a: Easy!
  b:
  c: 2
  d: [3, 4]
`
m := yaml.MapSlice{}
err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
}
fmt.Printf("--- m:\n%v\n\n", m)
```

Comment: Nice example - but in most cases we know the under type. So I want to keep order of `map[string]*MyType` Is there easy solution for this? @hobbs

Comment: The problem seems impossible to solve when attempting this at a deeper level of the yaml tree. A show stopper?